# Docker ps disappeared after restart system

Tags: docker

Run docker container on a Linux system. From `docker ps` can see all the processes.

After restart the system and run `docker ps` can't see some containers, but use `docker ps -a` can see them. Is the container still running?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't set the option `--restart=always` when run the docker container, these containers will not be started automatically, after you restart the system.

> Restart policies (–restart)
>
> always - Always restart the container regardless of the exit status. When you specify always, the Docker daemon will try to restart the container indefinitely. The container will also always start on daemon startup, regardless of the current state of the container.

Refer: [docker run - Restart policies (–restart)](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#restart-policies-restart)

Comment: Thanks, chap. Apparently I had lost all my containers. Works fine now